# calculate crc32 in zipEntry of classes.dex in android java

Tags: java, android

I want to calculate CRC32 of classes.dex and compare it to check if tampered or not

I am thinking to use it as zipfile.getentry something like this below:

```
try{
    ApplicationInfo ai = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
    ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(ai.sourceDir);
    ZipEntry zen = zf.getEntry("classes.dex"); 
}
```

and then calculate crc32 of classes.dex and return it as a string.

anybody can help to fix it up.

I want (ZipEntry fname) to calculate I do not want to extract the apk and use classes.dex as string to calculate I want zipentry to calculate on the go without extracting from the app

Comment: And what is the problem that you are facing now?

Comment: i want correct checksum like winrar shows on PC thats what im not getting PS i want to calculate checksum from zipentry ,i do not want to extract the apk :)

Comment: i can calculate md5 with myself but i just wanna do something else bro :)

Answer (score 1):

> I want (ZipEntry fname) to calculate

Well bad luck, it doesn't.

> I do not want to extract the apk and use classes.dex as string to calculate I want zipentry to calculate on the go without extracting from the app

Bad luck again, you gotta.

Comment: yes i did this way only because i was not left with any choice :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.CRC32;
import java.util.zip.Checksum;

public class ComputeCRC32 {
  public static long getChecksumValue(Checksum checksum, String fname) {
    try {
       BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(
         new FileInputStream(fname));
       byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
       int len = 0;

       while ((len = is.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
         checksum.update(bytes, 0, len);
       }
       is.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return checksum.getValue();
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length != 1) {
      System.err.println("Usage: java ComputeCRC32 <file>");
      System.exit(1);
    }
    long cs = getChecksumValue(new CRC32(), args[0]);
    System.out.println("crc32 " + args[0] + " : " + cs);
  }
}
```

Source: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0416.html it also contains other solutions, find the best one for you there :)

Comment: i have better code than this i actually wants (ZipEntry fname) not String i can use string after extracting i know but i do not want to extract the apk just calculate on the go :)

Comment: @helloworldandroid Please capitalize and punctuate your questions and comments. This is just gobbledygook.